# Remove margin responsive thumbnail grid

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, thumbnails

I creating a thumbnail grid that has a responsive 4-3-2-1 column structure: 25%, 33.33%, 50%, 100%. But i want to be able to remove the last margin of each thumbnail in every state so with 4 columns (25%,25%,25%,25%) or 3 columns (33.33%, 33.33%, 33.33%) etc. Now the last thumbnail jumps under the other thumbnails. I was trying to use :nth-child for this.

What is the best way of building a thumbnail grid with divs, unordered lists (ul) or maybe something else?

Can ayone help me with this? Thank you ;-)

Here example:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/7co5rfpo/)

or

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPZgXG)

```
.thumb:nth-child(4n) {
margin-right: 0;}
```

Comment: Your problem is that the size adds up to more than 100% as `width` refers to the contents of a box, doesn't include padding and never includes margin. As a start use `box-sizing: border-box` and `padding` instead of `margin` on the `.thumb`. This makes the width of e.g. 25% include the padding. After that try to see how Bootstrap implements its grid, a great article on this is http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

Comment: Going to try that first, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

Use [box sizing](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing). Change your `margin` to `padding` and use `box-sizing: border-box;` on your `.thumb`. This means it will take the padding and border into account when putting in percentage widths.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7co5rfpo/2/)

#### Option 2

Use [calc](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). Example:

```
.thumb {
   width: calc(50% - 20px);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7co5rfpo/3/)

I'll let you decide which is better for you based on browser support. :)

#### Update

To get rid of the margin on the right, you can use [nth-child](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child), sort of what you suggested:

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 601px) {
    .thumb {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .thumb:nth-child(2n+0) {
        padding: 0 0 20px 10px;
    }
}
```

See the bottom example on [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7co5rfpo/4/)

Comment: Thank you for helping, but there is still a right margin on the 4th thumbnail :-)

Comment: potentially you could change your padding to `:0 10px 20px 10px;`, or is having it touch both edges an absolute must?

Comment: Updated answer for getting rid of the excess padding/margin

Comment: Thanks Jamie for helping but i just want a clean thumbnail grid with a 500x310 ratio and 20px margin space between them and responsive 4,3,2,1 etc, but i also don't want to use padding because i want to show a image holder (background color red for example) with a loader on it before the images are loaded with the same size as the image. Hope you understand, but now the padding is outside the image and also the space between the thumbnails isn't the same when do they build software so i just can design quickly it is such a hassle to get this working and this is only the beginning frustrating!